# Azure maximize button missing.

Tags: azure

Not a code question but its stopping me from writing any code.   In Azure the maximize button on easy tables is missing in all browsers including Safari, Chrome and Firefox.  Also emulating Internet Explorer and Edge in Safari gives the same result. Im on a Mac and don't have access to a windows machine. This button was right next to the close button, now its gone.  Has anyone seen this issue or found a fix? [image]

Answer (score 1):

They removed it some time ago (not sure the reasoning behind this, annoying as hell). Nothing you can do about it. Well, you can créate a feedback ítem. thats about it.

I'm using a Windows\Centos laptop, so you can be sure your OS is not the issue.
update:

you can kinda work around it:

> I found a fix just now. Grab the right side of the browser window and
>   drag to the left to make it small. The button appears! If you drag and
>   make the window larger the button disappears.

Comment: Wow.  This is a deal breaker. Its enough to make me change backends.

Comment: My guess is if this is important enough for you - raise a feedback ítem. for me its a minor annoyance, i'm lazy to créate a feedback for this, but if you créate it i would be able to promote it a bit directly\indirectly with the PG

Comment: I found a fix just now.  Grab the right side of the browser window and drag to the left to make it small.  The button appears! If you drag and make the window larger the button disappears.  What is PG?

Comment: PG = Product Group

Comment: Report the bug here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback and on twitter @AzureSupport for some visibility

Comment: Ive reported.   https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/33168220-easy-table-maximize-button-missing

Comment: mailed this thread to the folks working on this ;) cross your fingers ;)